# Creating map-based online questionnaire/survey?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, arcgis-online, software-recommendations, google-maps-api

I am planning to create map-based online questionnair/survey for my master dissertation on bicyle safety. What I want to do is, asking my potential respondants to mark their answers by adding pins/mark on Online map I create. For example, I ask them a question like, " where did you have a near-miss incident while you are on a bicycle?", then respondant can answer that question by locating pins/mark on where they had nearmiss.

My initial investigaton suggested that I can achieve this with Google map API, ArcGIS online or Crowdmap. I have seen some crowd-sourced maps with a lot of pins located by many people. But I am not sure if I can;

1. download all these marked locations in csv/text file with xy coordinate
2. make my survey map accessable only for my "group"

Can anybody suggest me what can I use (Google API, crowdmap, ArcGIS online or else) to achieve above 1 and 2 without any or with little programming?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. It isn't clear what you are really asking here. Asking for "best" isn't in scope (because its subjective) for this site, and you don't appear to have a single well-defined question. Can you click edit below the question to make it something that can be answered in a few paragraphs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CrowdMap can be best choice. It does both 1 and 2.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about this software, and how it can be used by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Without any programming, I dont know any.

But one idea could be to ask location in your questionnary (ex: address, street name or postal code) and then use a geocoder (for reverse geocoding) to produce a map.

I think your results would be more precise because pinning a marker on a map is often approximative, it could depends on the map scale, user's skills or interpretation, etc...

Answer (score -1):

I think that you would be really interested in some of the most cutting-edge research that I have come across explaining crowds, open innovation, and citizen science.​

http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=1919614

And you may also enjoy this blog about the same too: 
https://thecrowdsociety.jux.com/